How can an Android app receive UI updates without HTTP requests?
I am trying to reverse engineer an API of an app. I have already done everything there is to decrypt traffic using Charles and HTTP Toolkit certificates on a rooted Android emulator. However, both Charles and HTTP Toolkit show a weirdly small amount of requests. All of them are decrypted and there is no unknown traffic shown, but the only requests i get are media requests (mostly video thumbnails), one AB config request, then some Facebook and Firebase integration requests and that is it. Seems like the app does not get UI data by making http requests to a server. It might use gRPC, but Charles supports HTTP/2, and even if it did not, i tried Mediator that is aimed at gRPC calls and got nothing. I am not an Android developer so i do not really know about UI rendering on Android, what could it be that there is no data incoming for the app?

HTTP has nothing to do with drawing the UI of an app.  Not all apps even make HTTP requests-  do you think your calculator app needs to access a website?  Do you think every time you tap a button in an app it makes an HTTP request?  Not even actual web apps work like that.  I think maybe you want to ask about how it gets additional data needed to display things, but if so you need to word your question better so we can answer it correctly.

Make sure the app can not bypass the proxy. Some apps (or app parts) ignore proxy configuration. Easiest way would be to use mitmproxy in Wireguard mode. When Wireguard VPN is active there is only the way through mitmproxy.

@GabeSechan HTTP has a lot to do with drawing UI, because the data that components render has to be received by the client somehow. Web apps may choose to fetch data as JSON and render the UI or use SSR, SSG or a mix of those, you name it. I understand that some parts of the app may not need to request data as it is static, but when we are talking about views under a video or sub count of a channel, this type of data is definitely dynamic and needs to be fetched before rendering. I apologise for poor question phrasing

@steak_Overcooked No, HTTP has NOTHING to do with drawing UIs.  It might have to do with getting data into an app.  But that's a different thing altogether.  Drawing does not use the network at all.  I think I get what you're trying to ask, but your question is poorly worded enough I can't be sure.

There's a variety of other ways it can get data.  It can be preloaded in the app.  It can be generated by the app.  It can have previously been loaded and then cached.  It can have been sent over the network via non-HTTP protocols.  It can have been pushed down via push message (a particular type of non-HTTP protocol).  You're mixing up all kinds of layers of software design there that really have nothing to do with one another.

Can you provide the sample apk so that we can also test it from our side?

It turns out the app is not using http but rather a raw socket connection with protobuf. Data is also encrypted, so the only way to reverse engineer the API is to disassemble the apk and read the smali. Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

The most plausible explanation would be that the UI components and their logic is already written and available in the application. The Activities (android component where UI logic is written) in your application are then loading the Views (a UI component with a behavior) based on the data it gets from various sources.
If you can deobfuscate the code, try checking the activities for any UI logic.
Another possibility is a Server-Driven UI framework being used, some example frameworks would be Epoxy, Lithos, RIBs (more of an architecture/framework).
Here is an article that I referred to: https://medium.com/basalam/server-driven-ui-in-android-with-compose-bf1885e9343c.
I hope this information is helpful!
Edit: Added reference article.

Thanks, i am going to check it out and update you with what i got
